# Trouble with Telegram bot streaming live and playing music in a channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm currently working on a **Telegram bot** using the **python-telegram-bot library**. The bot is designed to stream live content and play music in a channel. I've encountered issues where the bot, despite being an admin in the channel, is unable to **open a live stream and play music**.

```
import os
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, CommandHandler

TOKEN = '*********' # Replace with your token
CHANNEL_ID = '*********'  # Replace with your channel ID

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Welcome to the bot!')

def play(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id

    try:
        # Print user ID and status for debugging
        print(f"User ID: {user_id}")
        chat_member = context.bot.get_chat_member(CHANNEL_ID, user_id)
        print(f"User Status: {chat_member.status}")

        # Check if the user is an admin in the channel
        if chat_member.status in ['administrator', 'creator']:
            # Check if the message has an audio file
            if update.message.audio:
                # Download the audio file
                audio_file = update.message.audio.get_file()
                audio_file_path = os.path.join('downloads', f"{audio_file.file_id}.mp3")
                audio_file.download(audio_file_path)

                # Join the voice chat and play the audio file
                voice_chat_id = update.message.chat_id
                context.bot.send_voice(voice_chat_id, voice=open(audio_file_path, 'rb'))

                # Cleanup: Delete the downloaded audio file
                os.remove(audio_file_path)
            else:
                update.message.reply_text('Please reply to an MP3 file with the /play command.')
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('You are not an admin in the channel.')

    except Exception as e:
        update.message.reply_text(f'Error: {e}')

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("play", play))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.audio & Filters.reply, play))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

. However, when I try to send an MP3 file to the bot privately or within the channel and issue the command /play, the bot responds with the message "You are not an admin in the channel. but User Status is creator"
please fix it. thanks